# Destroy Bootstrap Carousel Plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using carousel view in my ember application.  Is there any way to destroy the carousel plugin, after we move to a different view?? The work-around currently I am using is:

```
 willClearRender: function () {
   this._super();
   this.$().carousel('pause');
   this.$().off('bs.carousel.data-api'); 

 }
```

Not sure whether it is correct. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? See also http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events: "All infinitive events provide preventDefault functionality. This provides the ability to stop the execution of an action before it starts."

Comment: @BassJobsen, With my work-around, the plugin is not getting detached from the DOM. I can see my plugin's html under "Detached DOM tree" when I take the heap snapshot. I want to destroy the plugin completely, so that it does not cause any memory leakage.

Comment: set `jQuery.fn.carousel = null;` maybe

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the bootstrap 3 carousel plugin by adding this function:

```
Carousel.prototype.destroy = function () {
    this.hide().$element.off('.' + this.type).removeData('bs.' + this.type)
}
```

Right after **Carousel.prototype.slide** function

and then you call it like that

```
willClearRender: function () {
   this._super();
   this.$().carousel('pause');
   this.$().carousel().destroy(); 

}
```